# How to write a single query by not using multiple inserts where all customers will have another address 3 with the same respective addresses?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table customer like below in SQL SERVER,

```
CUSTOMER(CUSTOMERID,ADDRESSID,ADDRESSTYPEID)
values(1,1001,2);(2,1002,2);(3,1003,2);(4,1004,2)
```

How to write a single query by not using multiple inserts where all customers will have another address 3 with the same respective addresses?

Answer (score 1):

```
insert into customer_address (customerid, addressid, addresstypeid)
select customerid, addressid, 3
from customer_address
where addresstypeid = 2 /* where might not be needed */
```

To insert only for those customers who do not yet have an `addresstypeid` of 3:

```
insert into customer_address (customerid, addressid, addresstypeid)
select customerid, addressid, 3
from customer_address c
where addresstypeid = 2
  and not exists (
    select 1
    from customer_address i
    where i.customerid = c.customerid 
      and i.addresstypeid = 3
      )
```